# Can the CIL evaluation stack contain value types?

Tags: .net, clr, cil, value-type

I'm a little confused about value types and the CIL evaluation stack.
ECMA-335, Partition III, §1.1 says that the CLI deals with these "Basic CLI types":

> - A subset of the full numeric types (int32, int64, native int, and F).
> - Object references (O) without distinction between the type of object referenced.
> - Pointer types (native unsigned int and &) without distinction as to the type pointed to.

Partition II, §12.1 also provides a similar list which excludes value types, and states:

> However, the CLI supports only a subset of these types in its operations upon values stored on its evaluation stack— int32 ,  int64 , and native int.

This makes no mention of value types other than through managed pointer types. Yet the specification for `ldfld`, for example, says:

> The ldfld instruction pushes onto the stack the value of a field of
> obj. obj shall be an object (type O), a managed pointer (type &), an
> unmanaged pointer (type native int), **or an instance of a value type**.

Does this mean value types can be pushed directly on the evaluation stack (as opposed to via a managed pointer)? If so, can I assume that the value type being pushed is a memberwise copy of the original (the field value, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section I.12.3.2.1 of [ISO/IEC 23271:2012](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=58046) (CLI Specification) states the following:

> While the CLI, in general, supports the full set of types described in §I.12.1, the CLI treats the evaluation stack in a special way. While some JIT compilers might track the types on the stack in more detail, the CLI only requires that values be one of:
>
> - `int64`, an 8-byte signed integer
> - `int32`, a 4-byte signed integer
> - `native int`, a signed integer of either 4 or 8 bytes, whichever is more convenient for the target architecture
> - `F`, a floating point value (float32, float64, or other representation supported by the underlying hardware)
> - `&`, a managed pointer
> - `O`, an object reference
> - `*`, a “transient pointer,” which can be used only within the body of a single method, that points to a value known to be in unmanaged memory (see the CIL Instruction Set specification for more details. * types are generated internally within the CLI; they are not created by the user).
> - **A user-defined value type**

So, yes, the evaluation stack can contain a value type. And that value type is copied.

Answer (score 2):

See the introduction to III.1.1 (emphasis mine):

> While the CTS defines a rich type system and the CLS specifies a
>   subset that can be used for language interoperability, the CLI itself
>   deals with a much simpler set of types. **These types include
>   user-defined value types** and a subset of the built-in types.  The
>   subset, collectively called the “basic CLI types”, contains the
>   following types:

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ldfld definitely copies a value type value onto the eval stack.  The "basic CLR types" are the ones that can appear as an operand to its *operations*.  Review table III.2 for example, shows you want kind of operands can be used for the *add* instruction for example.  Just int32, int64, native int, F, O and & appear there.

Also the core reason why C# requires a cast to copy the result of adding to byte values back into a value of type byte.  Not a basic CLR type so it gets converted to int32 and produces an int32 result.  Fitting it back into a byte is a non-trivial conversion.